# importing fixture data from mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Is there anyway to import data using mysqldump rather than fixtures during a test (rake test:profile in this case).

I have not been successful in exporting mysql data in yml format (which works ok) and importing it into rails (doesn't work, rake task complains about formatting of the yml file whose integrity seems intact).

What are some other days to export/import data with or without fixtures?

Comment: I hate when I ask a question about doing something specific and someone says,"Why don't you do something else instead." So I'm leaving this as a comment... Have you tried using something like Faker instead of importing actual data? You can add a rake task to create dummy accounts in your test database. If you're interested in something like that I can post how but I didn't want to be a putz and leave an answer not actually answering you.

Comment: Yes I have tried faker..its just that it's just easier to import (if there is an easy way) rather than write methods that accurately create interesting data. Thanks for the comment

Comment: It's not easier if you can't get it to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mysqldump is a command line program so you'd have to write a rake job to clear out your DB.  I agree with Mike B though.  There's general advice like "Fat Model, Skinny Controller" that goes "Factories Not Fixtures" from [a railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures) covering the subject.  The advantage of factories is that they can roll back the DB between each test if you so choose.  Fixtures also have the disadvantage of not representing relations very easily, you have to create and maintain the primary/foreign keys by hand.  It's kind of a pain.

If I really had to stick with fixtures, I'd not import data to test with.  Testing your database is out of scope of your app.  If your app really depends on data being there, then put it in seeds.rb.  But application data shouldn't need to be tested.  For example, I really don't care what's in the table Users, field first_name.  If I did, I'm writing a data tester?

Also, I hope you're not dumping production data into a test database and then testing that.  It's excessive to do so.

If you still want to use mysqldump and fixtures, write a rake task or a script to do the following:

- First, use mysqldump to dump out your data you want to use.
- Trim down the insert statements to a few rows per table.  Make sure you have some relations in there!
- Convert these rows to fixtures files or write a script to do a mysql command like this:

  - mysql -u dbuser --password=password dbname < few_rows_from_mysqldump.sql
- Run tests
- Truncate tables referenced in few_rows_from_mysqldump.sql

This is essentially what the transaction feature of something like factory_girl does.  Just be aware that you'd be reinventing the wheel a little bit.

Fixtures are fine to use, you just have to create the PK/FK by hand.  Because of that, I usually test with only a few rows.  Anything more than that is testing the database layer which is out of scope.  If you want to ensure data is of a certain quality, add database constraints with "validates_blah_blah" in your model.

Hope I didn't do the "do something else instead" too much like Mike B said.  I agree that's annoying.  But I also want to advise.